# convert dataframe to transformed dataframe in spark scala

Tags: pandas, scala, apache-spark

So, I have a DataFrame in Spark which looks like this:

```
[name,target] this is the header
[ABCD,1]
[XYZA,1]
[GFFD,1]
[NAAS,1]
[ABCD,2]
[XYZA,2]
[NAAS,2]
[VDDE,2]
```

And I want to convert it into dataframe like this

```
[name, count(target=1), count(target=2)]
[ABCD, 1,1]
[XYZA, 1,1]
[GFFD, 1,0]
AND SO ON.....
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are only 2 possible target values (1 and 2)?

Comment: there could be many maybe even 100 target values.

Comment: Then you might need to define more rules to your question, for example, what is the expected output if you have one `[ABCD,100]` ?? a list of 99 `0`'s and only a `1` at the end of that? Also, is not better to output a `name` + `ocurrences_map` ? where `key` will be the target value and `value` will be the count for that `key`?

Comment: This question could be improved by posting the code that you've tried. Please read about [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

These are two possible solutions.

Sample input data:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  ("ABCD",1),
  ("XYZA",1),
  ("GFFD",1),
  ("NAAS",1),
  ("ABCD",2),
  ("XYZA",2),
  ("NAAS",2),
  ("VDDE",2),
  ("EXAMPLE", 20)
).toDF("name", "target")

df.show()

+-------+------+
|   name|target|
+-------+------+
|   ABCD|     1|
|   XYZA|     1|
|   GFFD|     1|
|   NAAS|     1|
|   ABCD|     2|
|   XYZA|     2|
|   NAAS|     2|
|   VDDE|     2|
|EXAMPLE|    20|
+-------+------+
```

1 - Returning only the non-zero occurrences using a `map`.

```
case class DataItem(name: String, target: Int)

df.as[DataItem]
  .groupByKey(_.name)
  .mapGroups{
    case (nameKey, targetIter) =>{
     val targetList = targetIter.map(_.target).toSeq
     val occMap = targetList.groupBy(a=>a).mapValues(_.size)
      (nameKey, occMap)
    }
  }
  .toDF("name", "target_count").show()


+-------+----------------+
|   name|    target_count|
+-------+----------------+
|   VDDE|        [2 -> 1]|
|   NAAS|[2 -> 1, 1 -> 1]|
|EXAMPLE|       [20 -> 1]|
|   GFFD|        [1 -> 1]|
|   XYZA|[2 -> 1, 1 -> 1]|
|   ABCD|[2 -> 1, 1 -> 1]|
+-------+----------------+
```

2 - Using a list to display occurrences (including 0's), where the index = target_value.

```
case class DataItem(name: String, target: Int)

df.as[DataItem]
  .groupByKey(_.name)
  .mapGroups{
    case (nameKey, targetIter) =>{
       val targetList = targetIter.map(_.target).toSeq
       val occMap = targetList.groupBy(a=>a).mapValues(_.size)
       val maxTarget = occMap.maxBy(_._2)._1 
       val occList = for (i <- 1 until maxTarget+1) yield occMap.getOrElse(i, 0)

      (nameKey, occList)
    }
  }
  .toDF("name", "target_count").show(20, false)


+-------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|name   |target_count                                                |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|VDDE   |[0, 1]                                                      |
|NAAS   |[1, 1]                                                      |
|EXAMPLE|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]|
|GFFD   |[1]                                                         |
|XYZA   |[1, 1]                                                      |
|ABCD   |[1, 1]                                                      |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe can be transformed by "pivot":

```
  df
  .groupBy("name")
  .pivot("target")
  .count()
    // replace nulls with 0
  .na.fill(0)
```

With data provided by Cesar A. Mostacero, result is:

```
+-------+---+---+---+
|name   |1  |2  |20 |
+-------+---+---+---+
|EXAMPLE|0  |0  |1  |
|XYZA   |1  |1  |0  |
|GFFD   |1  |0  |0  |
|VDDE   |0  |1  |0  |
|ABCD   |2  |1  |0  |
|NAAS   |1  |1  |0  |
+-------+---+---+---+
```